# How to use struct of template class in own struct?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Im program A, I am declaring a struct called *Node* using another struct called *node_type* defined in template class *ab_int* provided by a lib B I am using.

Program A:

```
struct Node {
 int rank;
 ab_int::node_type nt;

 Node() : rank(), nt() {}
 Node( int rank_new, ab_int::node_type nt_new ) : rank( rank_new ), nt( nt_new ) {}
};
```

This is the template containing struct *node_type* in lib B:

```
template<class t_bitvector = bit_vector, ...>
class ab_int
{
   ...
   public: 
    struct node_type {
     ...
     // Assignment operator
     node_type& operator=(const node_type&) = default;

     // Move assignment operator
     node_type& operator=(node_type&&) = default;
     ...
    }

    ...
    node_type root() const {
        return node_type(0, m_size, 0, 0);
    }
    ...
}
```

In lib B, there is also a function *root()* I want to use.

In program A, I want to instantiate a new instance of struct *Node*:

```
// wt instantiated (works!)
Node node;
node.rank = 1;
node.nt = wt.root();
```

I am getting the following compile error:

```
.../main.cpp:23:5: error: expected a class or namespace
ab_int::node_type nt;
^
.../main.cpp:26:44: error: expected a class or namespace
Node( int rank_new, ab_int::node_type nt_new ) : rank( rank_new ), nt( nt_new ) {}
```

**Update 1:**

After changing `ab_int::node_type` to `ab_int<>::node_type`, a different error popped up:

```
.../main.cpp:63:13: error: no viable overloaded '='
node.nt = wt.root();
~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~
.../ab_int.hpp:752:24: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'z::ab_int<z::rrr_vector<63, z::int_vector<'\x00'>, 32>, z::rank_support_rrr<'\x01', 63, z::int_vector<'\x00'>, 32>, z::select_support_rrr<'\x01', 63, z::int_vector<'\x00'>, 32>, z::select_support_rrr<'\x00', 63, z::int_vector<'\x00'>, 32> >::node_type' to 'const z::ab_int<z::int_vector<'\x01'>, z::rank_support_v<'\x01', '\x01'>, z::select_support_mcl<'\x01', '\x01'>, z::select_support_mcl<'\x00', '\x01'> >::node_type' for 1st argument
        node_type& operator=(const node_type&) = default;
                   ^
.../ab_int.hpp:755:24: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'z::ab_int<z::rrr_vector<63, z::int_vector<'\x00'>, 32>, z::rank_support_rrr<'\x01', 63, z::int_vector<'\x00'>, 32>, z::select_support_rrr<'\x01', 63, z::int_vector<'\x00'>, 32>, z::select_support_rrr<'\x00', 63, z::int_vector<'\x00'>, 32> >::node_type' to 'z::ab_int<z::int_vector<'\x01'>, z::rank_support_v<'\x01', '\x01'>, z::select_support_mcl<'\x01', '\x01'>, z::select_support_mcl<'\x00', '\x01'> >::node_type' for 1st argument
        node_type& operator=(node_type&&) = default;
```

**Update 2:**

The second compile error was related with some inconsistencies regarding instantiation of object wt. Because isn't related to the original question, I don't discuss it any further.

Comment: Don't update your questions to ask different questions.

Comment: Although to the second question - looks like `node.nt` and `wt.root()` have different types (the first template arg is `z::rrr_vector<>` in one and `z:int_vector<>` in the other).

Comment: it's z:rrr_vector<>, corrected the mistake...

Comment: I wrote the wrong two types the first time around. It's `rrr` vs `int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `ab_int` is not a type, it's a *template*:

```
template<class t_bitvector   = bit_vector, ...>
class ab_int { .. };
```

And you are using it like a type:

```
struct Node {
   int rank;
   ab_int::node_type nt;
// ^^^^^^^^
```

Hence the error on "expected a class or namespace". You cannot syntactically use a template like that. The correct syntax would be to provide a specific instantiation of the `ab_int` template:

```
ab_int<bit_vector_type, ...>::node_type nt;
ab_int<>::node_type nt; // use defaults
```

Alternatively, you could make `Node` itself a template to forward those types to `ab_int` (depending on how well this fits your use-case):

```
template <typename t_bitvector = bit_vector, ...>
struct Node {
    typename ab_int<bitvector, ...>::node_type nt;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

In that cause we'd need to provide the additional `typename` keyword, since now `node_type` becomes a dependent type.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to avoid manually specify template arguments I'd suggest reading up on:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction

Using Template argument deduction can make templates more flexible and easier to maintain.  Templates are about writing generic code, so manually providing a template type parameter limits that.